# Intune Graph API data extracts - very little data to work with

Tags: api, azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Im curious if there is more data available for Azure AD devices / Intune devices from the Graph API to match up with the manual device reports available from both portals?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/ or Beta

developer . microsoft . com /en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/device

Below is what im looking at. Anyone had any success at getting more data from the API ?

[Data comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFhCr.png)

Comment: You included a dead link for your data comparison. When you fix it, please properly embed the image, placing a `!` in front: `![data comparison][url]`.

Comment: The link is not dead. I merely uploaded an image using what the platform tools do. First time poster.

Answer (score -1):

I'm an engineer working on Microsoft Intune, specifically on the integration between Microsoft Graph and Intune.

All the details available in the Intune Azure Portal can be found on the [managedDevice](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/intune_devicefe_manageddevice) entity. The Intune Azure Portal itself is built on top of the Microsoft Graph APIs, so anything you can see or do in the portal you can do via the APIs.

If you are still having problems finding specific APIs let me know, and I should be able to help you find the information.

Peter

Comment: Having troubles getting an auth token to function with the AAD registered app, granting the webapp access to intune data, and to query data from /managedDevice/. Raised a msft call today as a result. Using powershell.

Comment: Hi Peter, I believe my ask is more "how to" orientated. From setting up the Azure AD app registration, to assigning the delegate permissions to access Intune back end data via the app, and to query the data from using powershell (getting the auth token & rest query to get /managedDevices/ data out. 

I need to go back to our customer asking and showing them "This is what we need setup" - because im not an subscription admin for this particular customer.

The only other intune customer I have to test on uses hybrid so their intune has not been migrated to Azure.

Comment: For reference - I raised [REG:117061315884030]